# No activity days detection using R

Tags: r, date, datetime

I have a dataframe loaded in RStudio with information about numerous events (millions).

Each row is an entry of a single event and apart from other information it includes two attributes with date information. The first one contains the date when the event began and the second when it ended. But the events are not sequential so they might overlap in time.

```
                              fecha                   fecha_fin
7510607 2014-02-13 20:09:59.8270000 2014-02-27 09:55:40.9700000
7510608 2014-02-13 20:10:01.1870000 2014-02-27 09:55:42.5630000
7557931 2014-02-16 05:32:08.6230000 2014-02-16 14:03:19.4970000
```

What could be the best and most efficient option to find which calendar days had no activity (without any event in process)? Please, keep in my mind that the duration of the events must be taken into consideration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tend to use `foverlaps` from the `data.table` package for such cases, e.g.:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- fread("id,fecha,fecha_fin
7510607,2014-02-01 20:09:59.8270000,2014-02-10 09:55:40.9700000
7510607,2014-02-13 20:09:59.8270000,2014-02-27 09:55:40.9700000
7510608,2014-02-13 20:10:01.1870000,2014-02-27 09:55:42.5630000
7557931,2014-02-16 05:32:08.6230000,2014-02-16 14:03:19.4970000")
setkey(dt, fecha, fecha_fin)
set(dt, j = 1L, value = NULL)
dt <- dt[,lapply(.SD, as.POSIXct, tz = "CET"),.SDcols=1:2]

dt2 <- data.table(fecha=as.POSIXct(seq(min(as.Date(dt$fecha)), max(as.Date(dt$fecha_fin)), "1 day")))[,fecha_fin:=fecha+60*60*24-1]
as.Date(foverlaps(dt2, dt)[is.na(fecha) & is.na(fecha_fin),i.fecha])
# [1] "2014-02-11" "2014-02-12"
```

Comment: Your solution of course beats mine, but I have managed to get slightly better times changing your dt2 assignment to `dt2 <- data.table(
    fecha = seq(min(dt$fecha), max(dt$fecha_fin), by = '1 day')
  )[, fecha_fin := fecha]`, assuming of course that `dt$fecha` is already a date.

Comment: Posted the benchmarking results editing my answer, feel free to copy them here and I will remove the whole answer.

Comment: I have read that the fuction `findOverlaps` is faster than `foverlaps` when it is used in a large data set (https://www.r-bloggers.com/comparing-the-execution-time-between-foverlaps-and-findoverlaps/). Have you chosen `foverlaps` for a particular reason?

Comment: @daloman, for me the need to use "`GRanges` or `GRangesList` object" would be a good excuse to not use the `findOverlaps`.

Comment: @m-dz: Thanks for benchmarking. (I'm lazy so I'll leave the answer. :) ). @daloman: I chose `foverlaps` because it's convenient. There may be faster alternatives - feel free to add and benchmark them, too.

Answer (score 1):

**Update, with slightly modified code from lukeA:**

I hope there is nothing wrong with my benchmarking here...

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)
library(microbenchmark)

# Create dt ---------------------------------------------------------------

size = 99999
# With this size result is an empty set, check smaller sizes like 999 to confirm
# results are same for both functions

create_dt <- function() {
  set.seed(2016)
  dt <- data.table(
    ID = 1:size,
    fecha = sample(
      seq(ymd('2000/01/01'), ymd('2016/11/16'), by="day"),
      size, replace = TRUE)
  )
  dt[, fecha_fin := fecha + sample(1:3, size, replace = TRUE)]
  setkey(dt, fecha, fecha_fin)
  set(dt, j = 1L, value = NULL)
  dt <- dt[,lapply(.SD, as.POSIXct, tz = "CET"),.SDcols=1:2]
}

dt <- create_dt()

# Declare functions -------------------------------------------------------

f_mdz <- function() {
  dt_2 <- data.table(
    fecha = seq(min(dt$fecha), max(dt$fecha_fin), by = '1 day')
  # Function simplified here!!!
  )[, fecha_fin := fecha]
  # ---------------------------
  as.Date(
    foverlaps(dt_2, dt)[is.na(fecha) & is.na(fecha_fin),i.fecha])#,
    # origin = '1970-01-01')
}

f_lukeA <- function() {
  dt2 <- data.table(
    fecha = seq(min(dt$fecha), max(dt$fecha_fin), "1 day")
  )[,fecha_fin:=fecha+60*60*24-1]
  as.Date(
    foverlaps(dt2, dt)[is.na(fecha) & is.na(fecha_fin),i.fecha])
}

# Benchmark! --------------------------------------------------------------

microbenchmark(
  dt_mdz <- f_mdz(),
  dt_lukeA <- f_lukeA(),
  times = 100)

# Unit: milliseconds
#                  expr      min       lq      mean   median       uq      max neval cld
#     dt_mdz <- f_mdz() 46.96793 55.11631  95.59214 60.33659 191.5536 212.4523   100   a
# dt_lukeA <- f_lukeA() 50.57496 56.42464 105.07356 60.81974 194.0779 211.8037   100   a

identical(dt_mdz, dt_lukeA)
```

**Old answer here:**

A point of departure (far from being efficient, e.g. row-wise operations on `data.table`...) for further investigation could be:

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)
library(magrittr)

dt <- data.table(
  ID = c(7510607L, 7510608L, 7557931L),
  fecha = ymd(c('2014-02-15', '2014-02-16', '2014-02-11')),
  fecha_fin = ymd(c('2014-02-27', '2014-02-27', '2014-02-12'))
)
#         ID      fecha  fecha_fin
# 1: 7510607 2014-02-15 2014-02-27
# 2: 7510608 2014-02-16 2014-02-27
# 3: 7557931 2014-02-11 2014-02-12

# Make the data "long"
long_dt <- dt[, .(days = seq(fecha, fecha_fin, by = '1 day')), by = ID]

# Get the diff with days sequence from min to max date
setdiff(
  seq(long_dt[, min(days)], long_dt[, max(days)], by = '1 day'),
  long_dt[, sort(unique(days))]
) %>% as.Date(origin = '1970-01-01')
# [1] "2014-02-13" "2014-02-14"
```

Please note I have changed your data to actually have two days (2014-02-13 and 2014-02-14) without any activity.

Comment: Looks like you are ignoring the time component.

Comment: @Marichyasana, the OP asked 'to find which calendar days', so I have assumed that processing 2014-02-13 20:09:59.8270000 and 2014-02-13 would give the same results, won't it?

Comment: So if an event starts on some day at 8:00AM and ends on the same day at 5:00PM you say no event occurred because the day is the same?

Comment: No, the event occurs on that day, which will be taken into account. Try the code with `dt <- data.table(
  ID = c(7510607L, 7510608L, 7557931L),
  fecha = ymd(c('2014-02-15', '2014-02-27')),
  fecha_fin = ymd(c('2014-02-15', '2014-02-27'))
)`

Answer (score 0):

A base R solution would be this:

```
df$fecha <- strptime(df$fecha, "%Y-%m-%d")
df$fecha_fin <- strptime(df$fecha_fin, "%Y-%m-%d")

dates_list <- lapply(1:3, function(x){

  interval_events <- seq(from = df$fecha[x], to = df$fecha_fin[x], by = "days")

})

interval_events  <- unique(do.call("c", dates_list))

interval_complete <- seq(from = min(df$fecha), max(df$fecha_fin), by = "days")

interval_complete[!(interval_complete %in% interval_events)]
#[1] "2014-02-13 CET" "2014-02-14 CET"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple one! You just expand the dates and take a union of all the dates.

```
## Data
dt1=as.Date(c('2014/01/01','2014/01/08','2014/01/05'))
dt2=as.Date(c('2014/01/10','2014/01/14','2014/01/05'))
df=data.frame(id=sample(1:3), dt1=dt1, dt2=dt2)
## Code
date=apply(df, 1, function(x) seq(as.Date(x[2]), as.Date(x[3]), by="day"))
event_dates=as.Date(Reduce(union, date), origin = "1970-01-01")
```